# Joining a range of dates to a pattern

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a unique problem. Consider that I have a column containing a list of single dates. E.g. 01 Feb 2024 to 01 Mar
2024.

I also have a table containing a pattern. The pattern has a start date (for example 01 Jan 2023) and is a pattern of shifts. For example, the table contains a number of rows with DAYNUMBER referring to an offset from the pattern start date. 1 meaning 01 Jan 2023, 2 meaning 02 Jan 2023, and so on.

How could I somehow match the dates in table 1 with the appropriate shift from table 2, given that there is no specific date in table 2 to join on?

I have tried to conceptualise using the day offset to align to the dates in table 1 however I have been unsuccessful.

Comment: Instead of me (us) trying to *imagine* what you have, why wouldn't you provide sample data and desired result (based on values you provided)?

Comment: Would be helpful if you could provide examples, so the the requirement will be clear

Answer (score 1):

You need to know 3 things:

1. An epoch date that the pattern starts from.
2. The length of the pattern.
3. Which days are valid within the pattern.

If you do not have all of that information then it is impossible.

---

So, if you have the tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE shifts (id, epoch, duration) AS
SELECT 1, TRUNC(DATE '2024-01-01', 'IW'), 14 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2024-01-01', 10 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE shift_patterns (shift_id, day) AS
  SELECT 1, LEVEL
  FROM   DUAL
  WHERE LEVEL NOT IN (2, 6, 10, 13)
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 14
UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, LEVEL
  FROM   DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5;

CREATE TABLE work_day (person_id, shift_id, day) AS
SELECT 1, 1, DATE '2024-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 1, DATE '2024-02-05' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2, DATE '2024-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2, DATE '2024-02-05' FROM DUAL;
```

Then you can calculate the number of days between the work day and the epoch day, take the modulus of the length of the shift pattern and add 1 and that is the day within the pattern.

```sql
SELECT w.person_id,
       w.shift_id,
       w.day,
       s.epoch,
       s.duration,
       p.day AS shift_day,
       MOD(w.day - s.epoch, s.duration) + 1 AS calculated_shift_day
FROM   work_day w
       INNER JOIN shifts s
       ON (w.shift_id = s.id
          AND w.day >= s.epoch)
       LEFT OUTER JOIN shift_patterns p
       ON (   s.id = p.shift_id
          AND MOD(w.day - s.epoch, s.duration) + 1 = p.day)
```

Which, for the sample data, outputs:

| PERSON_ID | SHIFT_ID | DAY | EPOCH | DURATION | SHIFT_DAY | CALCULATED_SHIFT_DAY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2024-01-01 00:00:00 | 2024-01-01 00:00:00 | 14 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2024-02-05 00:00:00 | 2024-01-01 00:00:00 | 14 | 8 | 8 |
| 2 | 2 | 2024-01-01 00:00:00 | 2024-01-01 00:00:00 | 10 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2024-02-05 00:00:00 | 2024-01-01 00:00:00 | 10 | *null* | 6 |

The final row contains a non-working day and the `OUTER JOIN` does not find a matching pattern row.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/MGof8kuY)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the question - you are asking about how to join two tables by date column of the first and using starting date of pattern and daynumber of the second. If that is the case then with some data like_

```sql
WITH    -- dates from 01.02.2024 till 31.03.2024
    tbl AS
        ( Select LEVEL "ID", DATE '2024-02-01' + (LEVEL - 1) "A_DATE"
          From Dual
          Connect By LEVEL <= 60
        ), 
    patterns AS
        ( Select    101 "ID", 12 "DAYNUMBER", 'some other col value 101' "SOME_COL", DATE '2024-01-01' "STARTING_DATE" From Dual Union All
          Select    102,  7, 'some ... 102', DATE '2024-01-01' From Dual Union All
          Select    103, 28, 'some ... 103', DATE '2024-01-01' From Dual Union All
          Select    104, 34, 'some ... 104', DATE '2024-01-01' From Dual Union All
          Select    105, 45, 'some ... 105', DATE '2024-01-01' From Dual Union All
          Select    106, 19, 'some ... 106', DATE '2024-01-01' From Dual Union All
          Select    107, 52, 'some ... 107', DATE '2024-01-01' From Dual Union All
          Select    108, 69, 'some ... 108', DATE '2024-01-01' From Dual 
        )
```

put Inner Join (or Left) like below...

```sql
--   S Q L :
Select        t.ID, t.A_DATE, p.ID "PAT_ID", p.DAYNUMBER, p.SOME_COL "P_SOME_COL"
From            tbl t
Inner Join  patterns p ON( p.STARTING_DATE + (DAYNUMBER - 1) = t.A_DATE )
```

```sql
/*    R e s u l t    for matching days (Inner Join)
        ID A_DATE       PAT_ID  DAYNUMBER P_SOME_COL              
---------- -------- ---------- ---------- ------------------------
         3 03.02.24        104         34 some ... 104            
        14 14.02.24        105         45 some ... 105            
        21 21.02.24        107         52 some ... 107            
        38 09.03.24        108         69 some ... 108          */
```

... if you change Inner To Left Join you will get all the dates from first table and the data from patterns just in matching rows (otherwise nulls).